# Refer to dataframe in function r

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to clean a number of dataframes which all have the same initial structure. As such i want to:

1. Write the code to clean one dataframe
2. Write a function for that code
3. Create a list of the dataframes
4. Use map (purr package) to iterate the function i created over the list of dataframes.

The problem i am having is how to have the function update the dataframe so that i get the clean dataframe saved as an object.

To make this clear:

Create one sample dataframe (all dataframes have the same format):

```
> df <- data.frame(X.1 = c("last.update", "trial.a", c(4,5,7)), X.2 = c("12/01/16", "trial.b", c(3,5,6)), stringsAsFactors = F)
> df
          X.1      X.2
1 last.update 12/01/16
2     trial.a  trial.b
3           4        3
4           5        5
5           7        6
```

Write the code to generate the clean dataframe:

```
> colnames(df) <- df[2, ]
> df <- df[-c(1,2), ]
> df
  trial.a trial.b
3       4       3
4       5       5
5       7       6
```

So i write a function:

```
scrub <- function(x) {
  colnames(x) <- x[2, ]
  x <- x[-c(1,2), ]
}
```

If i apply scrub to the original data frame nothing happens:

```
> df <- data.frame(X.1 = c("last.update", "trial.a", c(4,5,7)), X.2 = c("12/01/16", "trial.b", c(3,5,6)), stringsAsFactors = F)
> scrub <- function(x) {
+   colnames(x) <- x[2, ]
+   x <- x[-c(1,2), ]
+ }
> scrub(df)
> df
          X.1      X.2
1 last.update 12/01/16
2     trial.a  trial.b
3           4        3
4           5        5
5           7        6
```

Instead, to get the clean dataframe, i have to re-write the function so that it doesn't refer to x in the second line of the body, i then have to call the function on the dataframe and asign the result to an object:

```
> scrub <- function(x) {
+   colnames(x) <- x[2, ]
+   x[-c(1,2), ]
+ }
> df <- scrub(df)
> df
  trial.a trial.b
3       4       3
4       5       5
5       7       6
```

The issue then is i want to map (purr package) this function over multiple dataframes. That means i need the function to output the updated dataframe. If referring back to the dataframe in the second line of the body doesn't work, how can i achieve this.

I am sure this is a simple problem, but i can't seem to work it out.

Note: In reality the code that is cleaning these dataframes will be much longer doing much more than changing the colnames and deleting irrelevant rows.

Comment: If it is a list of datasets, you don't need to create or update an object in the global env. i.e. `library(tidyverse); lst(df, df) %>% map(~ .x %>% scrub)`

Comment: You need to assign the result. If I have `x = 1`, when I type `x + 2` the result (3) is computed, but not stored anywhere. If I want to modify `x`, I do `x <- x + 2`, and now `x` is 3. Your data frame and `scrub` function are the same. If you want to keep the result, overwriting the original, `df <- scrub(df)`. If you have a list of data frames, `list_of_df <- lapply(list_of_df, scrub)` (or use `purrr:map` or whatever, `list_of_df <- map(list_of_df, ~ scrub(.x)`). But you need to assign the result to keep it, just like in all the other cases.

Comment: The only function modification you need to make is to have the function return the whole result, make the last line of the function `x` (or more explicitly `return(x)`) and it will all work just fine. Or your `x[-c(1,2), ]` is fine too. It's equivalent to `x <- x[-c(1,2), ]; x`. It will  work just fine whether or not you are applying the function to a single data frame or not.

Comment: Perhaps i am misunderstanding something. @Gregor: I understand that i need to store the result hence `x <- x[-c(1,2), ]` in the second line or the body in my original function - but that doesn't work. If i add `return(x)` to the last line of my function it still doesn't work. All that gives is the updated df with the colnames updated but the redundant lines not deleted.@akrun: i am struggling to understand what the code you provide is doing.

Comment: It's not *in the function* that you need to do the assignment (you'd be fine, as I stated above, leaving it as `x[-c(1, 2), ]`.), it's assigning *the result of the function, when you call it `scrub(df)`* that you are (sometimes) missing. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's build a nice `scrub` function with an explicit return:

```
scrub <- function(x) {
  colnames(x) <- x[2, ]
  x <- x[-c(1,2), ]
  return(x)
}
```

Show that it works:

```
> df
          X.1      X.2
1 last.update 12/01/16
2     trial.a  trial.b
3           4        3
4           5        5
5           7        6
> scrub(df)
  trial.a trial.b
3       4       3
4       5       5
5       7       6
```

Above we see the original data, and that `scrub(df)` removes two rows. However, the output of `scrub(df)` has not been saved. `df` has not been modified because we did not assign the result of `scrub(df)` with an `<-`.

Next we'll show that the original data is still present in `df`. Then we'll assign the scrubbed version back to `df`, overwriting the original, and show that `df` is now modified:

```
> df
          X.1      X.2
1 last.update 12/01/16
2     trial.a  trial.b
3           4        3
4           5        5
5           7        6
> df <- scrub(df)   ## assign the result of scrub(df)
> df
  trial.a trial.b
3       4       3
4       5       5
5       7       6
```

Now `df` has been scrubbed, and the result saved.

Comment: Works perfectly. Sorry for not understanding this. I thought it was the second scrub function that i was adding the `return(x)` line to. Apologies for making you spell it out.